# Questions about SQL Server Full-Text Search Syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm trying to work out some of the finer details of the Full-Text Search syntax. I have the basics down but have run up against the following questions.

1. Near the top of [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;246800), it shows cases where double quotes are required and includes the example "oatmeal". Why does this need double quotes? Is this a typo?
2. Near the bottom of the [same page](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;246800), it states that any instances of `AND`, `AND NOT`, `OR`, or `OR NOT` should be wrapped in quotes in some cases. Why? Aren't these stop words anyway?
3. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) provides a number of examples that include quoted and unquoted search terms. What is the difference between `CONTAINS(Column, 'term')` and `CONTAINS(Column, '"term"')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Full text search uses double quotes as a text delimiter and its good practise to use them especially if you are likely to have more complex search terms. E.g. You can put phrases or words in double quotes.

```
"Oatmeal"
"Hot Oatmeal"
```

2) I think the logic in the "and and not or or not" section is for this is to find the boolean terms and wrap the content either side in quotes.

```
e.g. OatMeal or Hot Oatmeal
```

translate to

```
'"Oatmeal" or "hot oatmeal"'
```

rather than

```
'oatmeal "or" hot oatmeal'
```

3) It should be contains(column, 'terms') containstable would use the 3 term query containstable(table, column, 'terms') I have done some testing on a database here with 30k documents in it contains(*,'"dentist"') and contains(*,'dentist') returned the same 652 rows. Containstable returned them with the same ranking.

Comment: Thanks. So did you have an opinion if the statement about oatmeal needing to be in quotes a mistake then? Looks like there is no difference for my #3. I fixed the typos you pointed out.